# readinf file in C untill int appears

Tags: c, file, scanf

I want to read in a file which goes by the following format

```
char double int double int double int
char double int double int double int
int
double
```

The problem is the the appearance of the first two lines are unknown, there might be only 2 lines like this or more. (The rest of the file is constant so no problem there)

I use fscanf() and I know that it returns how many items have been read succesfuly. I wanted to use that but it turned out to be a failure, as I guess ints can be read as chars without a problem.

My code

```
int i = 0;
while(fscanf(file, "%c ", &race[i].tireType) != 0)
{
    fscanf(file, "%lf %d %lf %d %lf\n",
           &race[i].newLap,
           &race[i].wearoffLaps,
           &race[i].wearoffRate,
           &race[i].teardownLaps,
           &race[i].teardownRate);
    printf("%c: %lf %d %lf %d %lf\n", race[i].tireType, race[i].newLap, race[i].wearoffLaps, race[i].wearoffRate, race[i].teardownLaps, race[i].teardownRate);
    ++i;
}
```

How could I make this loop stop when the first letter in the current line is a number?

Comment: Read each line with `fgets()` and apply `sscanf()` to it, trying to convert two `%s`  strings (each stops at a whitespace). When you can't convert 2 strings (the return value from `sscanf()` is only `1`), you have reached the line containing `int`, which you can reprocess, as it is still there in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `scanf()` and friends don't return the number of read bytes, but instead return the number of items of the argument list successfully read & converted.

Then, before scanning `"%c"` you could first try to scan `"%lf"`. Depending on what that first added `fscanf()` returns, you can decide where in your file you are.

As the above is a bit hacky, alternatively, if your file(s) get more complicated, you could consider using Lex & Yacc to explicitly define the format/grammar of your file.

But since Lex & Yacc are probably overkill, you could also code a simple state-machine instead of the above suggested more hacky way of hard-coded if-else logic.

Generally speaking, it often helps to take a step back and think about why your file has this format. Then, from that understanding of your domain, think towards an implementation that as close as possible matches it (i.e., the real world where this file comes from). Don't just write code that works, but make it as meaningful as possible: meaning matters :-)